# ¿Como sacar el MAX y AVG en Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Como puedo sacar el maximo y el promedio de 2 columnas los campos son:

nombre, precio, cantidad.

Quiero sacar el maximo y el proximo por categoria

Comment: Probaste algo? esto esta en la documentacion de la DB y es relativamente simple. Con que problema te encontraste?

Comment: Si he probado pero no me ha  resultado

Comment: Y que fue lo que intentaste? es importante que muestres que intentaste, que errores tuviste, asi podemos ayudarte a corregir eso. y explicarte porque lo estas haciendo mal. si no, es solo replicarte el manual de la db para estas funciones.

Comment: @JuanPerez **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. Debes [edit] y mejorar tu pregunta. Agrega en la pregunta qué has intentado, qué errores tienes, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con esta consulta te va a funcionar

```
SELECT MAX(campo_tabla) AS maximo, AVG(campo_tabla) FROM nombre_tabla WHERE nombre = 'nombre_variable'
```

En donde se hace un `SELECT` con los campos que necesitas, `MAX` te hace la búsqueda el registro máximo que se encuentra en tu tabla, `AVG` saca el promedio `WHERE nombre = 'nombre_variable'` si necesitas el máximo por cada **nombre** `WHERE nombre = 'nombre_variable'` lo puedes hacer con el `where`

Saludos.